# Run jQuery code after previous script is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the Reevoo widget on my company's website to display reviews for the product the customer is currently viewing. I need to run another function once this function has fully completed.

```
<script id="reevoomark-loader"> 
  (function() { 
      var trkref = 'CEX'; 
      var myscript = document.createElement('script'); 
      myscript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      myscript.src=('http://mark.reevoo.com/reevoomark/CEX.js?async=true'); 
      var s = document.getElementById('reevoomark-loader'); 
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(myscript, s);
  })
();
</script>
```

This is the first script which gets the reviews from Reevoo. It takes a moment for the content to be placed in the page. Ideally, I don't want to add a `setTimeout` as the time will vary depending on user's computers. What I'm looking for is an `on complete` callback I can use with this existing code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use onload:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.onload = function() {
  //do what you need here
};
myscript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
myscript.src=('http://mark.reevoo.com/reevoomark/CEX.js?async=true'); 
var s = document.getElementById('reevoomark-loader'); 
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(myscript, s);
})
```